# mock a function inside python pyramid view

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, pyramid

I have a python pyramid view and want to write a unittest.

```
def home(request):
    state = request.params.get('redirect', None)
    cookie = request.headers.get('Cookie')              
    user = identify_session_user(cookie , request.registry.settings)
    response = HTTPFound(location=state)
    response.set_cookie('USERINFO',
                             base64.b64encode(json.dumps(user).encode('ascii')),
                             domain='test.com')


    return response
```

Simple unittest:-

```
def test_hello_world(self):
    from tutorial import home

    request = testing.DummyRequest()
    response = hello_world(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

How can I mock the idenfify_session_user function that is called inside my home view?

Comment: Please try to make the code in your questions more or less reproducible. At least include the relevant **imports** and ensure that the names are consistent. E.g. you are importing `home` but are calling `hello_world`. Also the very function you want to mock comes out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer your question, but is an alternative way to solve the problem.

Instead of mocking a view or the whole session machinery in Pyramid, you can do integration testing based on [WebTest](https://pypi.org/project/WebTest/). This might be easier to set up, but tests are little bit slower to run.

Comment: [Here are some WebTest and pytest based test examples I have out of my bat](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/master/tests/test_webhook_auth.py).